# Cannot destructure property `interface` of 'undefined' or 'null'. How to solve this?

Tags: solidity, web3js, javascript

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');

const provider = ganache.provider();
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');

let accounts;
let inbox;

beforeEach(async () => {
  // Get a list of all accounts
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  // Use one of those accounts to deploy the contract
  inbox = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(interface))
    .deploy({ data: bytecode, arguments: ['Hi there!'] })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });


  inbox.setProvider(provider);
});

describe('inbox', () => {
  it('deploys a contract', () => {
    assert.ok(inbox.options.address);
  });
  it('has a default message', async () => {
    const message = await inbox.methods.message().call();
    assert.equal(message, 'Hi there!');
  });
});
```

[image: ERROR]

Comment: shouldn't `beforeEach` be inside the `describe`?

Comment: No, if we do so we have to provide it inside all the describe (Local,global concept)

Comment: seems like an issue with your compile file. require('../compile')  is apparently returning null or undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error lies with the `require('../compile')`for sure as it must be returning a null.

Try referring to the code below for compilation of the solidity code.
Check if your compile.js file is working in the similar manner or not.

```
// Compile the source code
const input = fs.readFileSync('Coin.sol');

const output = solc.compile(input.toString(), 1);

const bytecode = output.contracts[':Coin'].bytecode;

const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':Coin'].interface);
```

**Make sure you got** `const abi = JSON.parse(output.contracts[':Coin'].bytecode);` **the 'C' of 'Coin.sol' in capitals in 'compile.js' cause that's just how it's stored in solidity**

Comment: How did you make it work? @shashvat

Comment: @urjitonrails simply check your compile.js file. Make sure you have got the first letter in caps as shown in the code above.

Answer (score 3):

The problem doesn't lie with the code provided. There's something wrong with your "compile" file.

```
const { interface, bytecode } = require('../compile');
```

is the issue,

```
require('../compile')
```

is returning `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: Yes, So how should I fix it ? I Bytecode is working. I am not sure about the inferface. Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Maybe post another question with your compile file if you can't figure it out. The bytecode isn't working either. The whole  `require('../compile')` evaluates to `undefined` or `null`. That's all that I can tell from what you've posted.

Comment: Also note, the error you've posted has nothing to do with Ethereum, it's just a Javascript error.

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure that you are exporting everything correctly from your `compile.js` file to your test file. I have spelling error when I was exporting contract, my code bit here `module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':Registration'];` the registration was `:registration` instead of `:Registration` and hence the `{interface, bytecode } were not being exported from the`compile.js`.

I hope this helps. It was a typo, js error.

Answer (score 1):

### **As i can't comment ngambinos post. This also worked for me here in 2021.**

**(thx to) ngambino0192:**

The issue is with this is likely the versioning of the solc compiler. Bumping the version's dependency to one that is more recent may solve your issue.

Try the following:

1. `rm -rf node_modules` // remove `node_modules`
2. `rm -rf package-lock.json` // remove `package-lock.json`
3. Change the .sol file's import statement to: `pragma solidity ^0.4.25`
4. Change the .sol file's import statement to: `pragma solidity ^0.4.25`
5. Change the dependency in package.json to `"solc": "^0.4.25"`
6. npm install // install new dependencies
7. Then you can run your tests

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the js file it's in the **.sol** file

1. Make sure that you are using solidity and solc version 0.4.17
2. Make sure that you are not using any functions of the new solidity version in your old version like **constructor**
3. It can be a basic syntax error in your compile.js file or .sol file

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error but make sure spelling of your contract name and the name you are using here:
module.exports = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts[':**Lottery**'];
and 
contract **Lottery**{
This must be identical.

Answer (score 0):

For googlers:

The issue is with this is likely the versioning of the solc compiler. Bumping the version's dependency to one that is more recent may solve your issue.

Try the following:

1. `rm -rf node_modules` // remove `node_modules`
2. `rm -rf package-lock.json` // remove `package-lock.json`
3. Change the .sol file's import statement to: `pragma solidity ^0.4.25`
4. Change the dependency in package.json to `"solc": "^0.4.25"`
5. `npm install` // install new dependencies

Then you can run your tests

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;
```

and

```
constructor() public {...}
```

instead of function

```
Lottery() public{...}
```

Using 0.4.25 solc version and constructor() is supported. Otherwise, error thrown like "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded" and "Cannot destructure property 'interface' of 'require(...)' as it is undefined".

I got these above error while running mocha test on my contract.

Delete node_module, package.lock.json and update solc version in contract as well as in package.json and reinstall using command "npm install"